# Do manually clicking "Release this version" override the "Availability Date" setting?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Before my app got approved, I set the "Availability Date" to 12/6/2014 accidentally (which is 2 days from now in my timezone). When my app got approved today, I clicked "Release this version". Now the app's status is already "Ready for Sale".

It has been 10 hours already and I still don't see my app on the Appstore.

Is this because of the availability date setting? or is it because the app is still processing?

When I clicked "Release this version", does it override the availability date setting?

I'm afraid that if I change the availability date setting now, it would remove the app from the appstore since the status is already "Ready for Sale". I read something about this somewhere, I'm not sure if this is correct.

More Info: I tried searching for my app on the appstore using a unique keyword I included as a tag of my app, the appstore yields 1 result, but the entry is not shown. It could very well be my app. Maybe this is because of the availability date?

Anybody knows?

Thanks

Comment: Just check the availability date of your app in the pricing section of 'itunes connect'.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the availability date to today or before, so it becomes visible. Currently, since the app availability date is in the future, the app can't appear in the App Store.

You should do so and wait for some hours till the servers get updated.